# What is the coefficient of x^k in (1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)(1+x^4)....(1+x^n)

Tags: math

I AM NOT ABLE TO GENERALISE IT

I am not able to generalise the sequence i tried so hard can anyone help me with it

I tried n=1,2,3,4,5,6 but not able to generalise it

Answer (score 1):

We can see that `x^k` coefficients are formed from sum of coefficients of the previous polynom using powers `1*x^k` and `x^n * x^(k-n)` (if the latter does exist).

So `C(n,k)=C(n-1,k)+C(n-1,k-n)` with some limits:

```
def expand(n, k):
    if n == 0:
        return 0 if k else 1
    if k > n * (n + 1) // 2:
        return 0
    res = expand(n - 1, k)
    if k >= n:
        res += expand(n - 1, k - n)
    return res

n = 3
for i in range(1 + n * (n + 1) // 2):
    print(expand(n, i), end = ' ')
print()
n = 5
for i in range(1 + n * (n + 1) // 2):
    print(expand(n, i), end = ' ')

1 1 1 2 1 1 1 
1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 1 1 1
```

For calculation of a lot of coefficients it would be wise to fill a table row-by-row to
avoid extensive recursion (a kind of dynamic programming)

```
def maketable(n):
    table = [[1],[1,1]]
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        table.append([0]*(1+i*(i+1)//2))
    for row in range(2, n+1):
        for k in range(1+row*(row-1)//2):
            table[row][k] = table[row-1][k]
        for k in range(row, 1+row*(row+1)//2):
           table[row][k] += table[row-1][k - row]
    return table

 print(maketable(5))
[[1], 
 [1, 1], 
 [1, 1, 1, 1], 
 [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1], 
 [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1], 
 [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]]
```